# IE fails to apply padding on text input with fixed width

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, input, padding

I have following, pretty basic, piece of html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <input id="username" value="CLICK ME TO SEE THE DIFFERENCE" type="text" />
</div>
```

I have some css rules that apply *width* and *padding* to **#username** input.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
input[type='text'] {
    width: 300px;
}
.applied-in-runtime input[type='text'] {
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

One of that rules is applied *right after page is loaded*, using jQuery:

```
$(function () {

    jQuery("#wrapper").addClass("applied-in-runtime");

});
```

Please check out strange IE behavior here: http://jsfiddle.net/pkawiak/MqAEE/

This occurs in IE10 (fails to apply horizontal padding), IE9 nad IE8 (they fail to apply both horizontal and vertical padding).

Interestingly, this glitch occurs only if width and padding are specified in different css classes **and** one of those classes is applied after page is loaded.

Do you see any way of fixing this issue except from applying class to wrapper div on server side or specifying both padding and width in one class?

Comment: not sure why that happens but a workaround [could be this](http://jsfiddle.net/MqAEE/40/)

Comment: This has got something to do with the box-sizing. I haven't got a reason, but if you comment out that property it works fine.

Comment: Code works fine in IE 10 when box-sizing is either `content-box` (default value) or `padding-box`. Another work-around (though I prefer Pete's method) would be to get the value of the input field and set the same back again to the field immediately after the class is applied.

Comment: `padding-box` doesn't work on all browsers (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)), so best avoid it. For inputs, `border-box` has the fewest compatibility problems.

Comment: Thanks guys, I guess I'll have to live with _content-box_ sizing after all.